# Flash[:notice] works in webrick but not in apache + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

This seems really strange and I'm at a loss to explain it.

```
flash[:notice] = "You must sign in before making a purchase."
return redirect_to new_user_session_path
```

This works fine in webrick development mode, and production mode. When I switch to apache no notices appears on the page, but the page loads find and there are no errors in the logs. I've been googling and some people suggested in similar questions that perhaps apache is redirecting twice, but the logs don't support this. Also, I tried `flash.keep[:notice]` just in case and that did not work either.

Any help would be most appreciated.

---

**Update:** Flash.now works fine (without the redirect of course). I believe at this point it's a permissions issue with apache / passenger not being able to store sessions correctly. I'll keep exploring this rabbit hole and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by using the [Active Record Session Store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) gem.